# Largest digit in a string using isdigit for python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to find the largest digit in a string of texts with alpha and numeric characters.

The source works in Python v2 but not in Python v3.  When I run the module in Python 3 it returns with an error "TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

```
largestdigit = 0
n = 5000

with open('pg76.txt') as file:
    sentence = file.read()

#FIND LARGEST DIGIT FOR SPECIFIED N SIZE

for i in range(0,n):
    if sentence[i].isdigit():
        if sentence[i] > largestdigit:
            largestdigit = sentence[i]

#OUTPUT

print ("loaded \"pg76.txt\" of length", len(sentence))
print ("n =", n)
if largestdigit == 0:
    print ("largest digit = None")
else:
    print ("Largest digit =", largestdigit )
```

Comment: @ZenOfPython This question is about an _incompatibility_ between 2.7 and 3.x.  So, the current tagging seems to make sense.  Are there other better tags for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
if sentence[i] > largestdigit:
```

you are trying to compare a string value with an integer value. Python does not automatically convert a string to an integer, so even though Python 2 doesn't show you an error, the code is not doing what you assume it is.

In Python 2, when you try to compare a string and an integer, the string ALWAYS evaluates to greater than the integer. So, in your code, sentence[i] will ALWAYS be greater than largestdigit, even if you set sentence[i] to '1' and largestinteger to 9.

In Python 3, instead of assuming that strings are always greater than integers, Python throws an error, which is what you are seeing.

You need to manually convert the string to an integer using the `int()` method. So, that line of code will become:

```
   if int(sentence[i]) > largestdigit:
        largestdigit = int(sentence[i])
```

EDIT: As user [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) mentioned in the comments,  another alternative is to make everything strings, in which case Python will evaluate them based on their ASCII code, and your digits comparison will work correctly. In this case, all you need to do is modify the line where you initialize `largestdigit`:

```
largestdigit = '0'
```

and also the comparision you make in the OUTPUT section:

```
if largestdigit == '0':
```

Comment: I would suggest change the initial value as a `str`: `largestdigit = '0'`

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` that you see was part of a deliberate change.  Python3 offers more complex and precise comparison operators and, as a result, the older "unnatural" comparisons have been removed.  This is documented as part of [What's New for Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> #### Python 3.0 has simplified the rules for ordering comparisons:
>
> The ordering comparison operators (<, <=, >=, >) raise a TypeError exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering.
>   Thus, expressions like 1 < '', 0 > None or len <= len are no longer
>   valid, and e.g. None < None raises TypeError instead of returning
>   False. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer
>   makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note
>   that this does not apply to the == and != operators: objects of
>   different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.

So, you need to either stick with characters or convert all the digits to integers.  If you choose conversion:

```
    if int(sentence[i]) > largestdigit:
        largestdigit = int(sentence[i])
```